# Is it allowed to add event to another bloc from inside of a bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management

I am using `bloc` library available in Dart to implement "bloc" pattern. I will eventually move onto `flutter_bloc` library so I can use it inside a real app.

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding how to create some general blocs that can be called  from within more specialized blocs. By specialized I mean some bloc that perhaps manages a specific view. General blocs would then take care of calling APIs or maybe even doing multiple things sequentially.

So my idea is that perhaps I have a `StateA` that manages certain model and for that reason I use `BlocA`. Whenever certain event is added to `BlocA`, I also need to update `StateB` that is managed by `BlocB`. I do not want to do this within same bloc because those different states contain different data that might be unrelated. Perhaps I can then have `BlocC` that is used for specific part of application but certain event should also invoke events and state changes in `BlocA` and `BlocB`.

I am considering writing `BlocA` bloc like this:

```dart
class BlocA extends BlocBase<BlocAEvent, BlocAState>  {
  BlocA(BlocB blocB) : super(BlocAState()) {
    _blocB = blocB;
    _blocARepository = BlocARepository();
  };

  BlocARepository _blocARepository;

  @override
  BlocAState mapEventToState(BlocAEvent event) async* {
    if (event is BlocAEventOne) {
      yield state.copyWith(valueOne: event.value);
    } else if (event is BlocAEventTwo {
      // Get data related to BlocAState
      final data = await _blocARepository.fetchImportantData()
      // ! <-- I also need to fetch additional data but that is managed
      // by different bloc - BlocB
      _blocB.add(BlocBEventOne(id: data.id));
      yield state.copyWith(dataList: SomeModel.fromJSON(data));
    }
  }
}
```

and then just creating regular bloc `BlocB` like this:

```dart
class BlocB extends BlocBase<BlocBEvent, BlocBState>  {
  BlocB() : super(BlocBState()) {
    _blocBRepository = BlocBRepository();
  };

  BlocBRepository _blocBRepository;

  @override
  BlocBState mapEventToState(BlocBEvent event) async* {
    if (event is BlocBEventOne) {
      // Get data related to BlocBState
      final data = await _blocBRepository.fetchOtherData(event.id)
      yield state.copyWith(dataList: SomeOtherModel.fromJSON(data));
    }
  }
}
```

I am really unsure if this is correct approach as basically `BlocA` adds another event. But I am trying to do some reusable blocs and keep data more separate. I know I could also do `_blocB.stream.listen` in `BlocA` but that only gives me the state of the `BlocB` bloc. What I need is the ability to react to certain events.

Do you think that my approach is perhaps convoluted and using `BlocObserver` would perhaps be more appropriate?
The problem with `BlocObserver` is that I am unsure how to use it properly from within Flutter app.

Comment: No,but you can communicate from one bloc to another. Here is the reference documentation https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, what you are trying to achieve is completely fine, but let's talk about the architecture a little bit.

One option could be that BLoC B subscribes to BLoC A state changes and handles that accordingly. For instance, here a more specific BLoC subscribes to changes of a more generic one: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/08200a6a03e37ce179cef10b65f34ddf6f43f936/examples/flutter_todos/lib/blocs/filtered_todos/filtered_todos_bloc.dart. For that, you would need to adjust the BLoC A state a bit (so you could identify this specific change/event) which could be not a way to go.

Another thing you should consider is whether you want to tightly couple your BLoCs (BLoC B reference is passed to BLoC A via constructor in your example). For that, you can create some kind of mediator class that uses streams inside: BLoC A could publish an event to that mediator class sink and all the subscribers will receive it via exposed streams (in your case - BLoC B should subscribe to that stream) - so the communication there would be like BLoC A -> Mediator -> BLoC B. That's basically what Mediator/Observer OOP design pattern resolves. The advantage of it is that your BLoCs won't know anything about each other, multiple BLoCs could subscribe to multiple different event streams, meaning you could add more subscribers (BLoCs) to your events at any point.

Comment: OP here. Thanks for the answer and thank you for the provided link. It is relief to hear that this behaviour is OK.
I'm OK to tightly couple blocs in some instances, I think it's OK to pass "general" BLoCs to more specialized ones (for example BLoC handling form state). But really it depends on situation.
I'm also thinking that instead of using `.stream.listen` it might be better to actually use `onTransition` method for more granular control.
Btw do you have example of such "Mediator" class implemented in Dart `bloc` library? Is this mediator class just another BLoC?

Comment: I've described the Mediator design pattern with example code here: https://mkobuolys.medium.com/flutter-design-patterns-22-mediator-575e7aa6bfa9 And Observer here: https://mkobuolys.medium.com/flutter-design-patterns-23-observer-1e1b0ea81d73

Comment: @mkobuolys What if the two blocs each both are equally involved in the process? I am trying to decouple a form (in a stepper) from the stepper, and having two different blocs for the process. One for the form(s). Another for the stepper. 

When I press "Next" on the Stepper Bloc, it should validate the form in the Form Bloc. If it is validated, Form Bloc should notify the Stepper Bloc, and the step should move forward.

Again, this is a more specific example, but what I am trying to achieve can be generalized for two blocs, both equally communicating with each other.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a callback in your event and invoke it in your bloc like this:

```
    blocA.add(BlocAEvent(whenDone: () {
      blocB.add(BlocBEvent())
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to listen to events being published by a BloC:

```
// Inside some widget
this.context.read<MyBloc>().listen((myBlocState) {
   if (mounted && myBlocState.isSomeState) {
      this.context.read<MyOtherBloc>().add(MyOtherBlocEvent());
   }
});
```

This solution would ensure your BloCs are not coupled and you can chain the publishing of your events based on the state of another BloC.